# Flow complaining about reduce returning a single boolean

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
export function subscriptionsReady(handles: Array<Object>): boolean {
  if (handles.length === 1) return handles[0].ready();

  return handles.reduce((a: any, b: Object): boolean => {
    return (typeof a === 'object' ? a.ready() : a) && b.ready();
  });
}
```

Flow errors:

```
  9:   return handles.reduce((a: any, b: Object): boolean => {
              ^ call of method `reduce`
  9:   return handles.reduce((a: any, b: Object): boolean => {
              ^ undefined (too few arguments, expected default/rest parameters). This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
  6: export function subscriptionsReady(handles: Array<Object>): boolean {
                                                                 ^^^^^^^ boolean
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `reduce` can return a value of the type in the array (in your case an `Object` type) if there's only one element in the array. I think that's why flow type is complaining about the return type. Maybe provide an initial value of `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the [type definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L208-L211) for `Array.prototype.reduce` expects the "memo" or the returned boolean to match the second parameter to `.reduce()`.

It seems however that you're actually trying to check that every single object within handles is `.ready()` in which case this might be better for you:

```
function subscriptionsReady(handles: Array<Object>): boolean {
  return handles.every((handle): boolean => {
    return handle.ready();
  });
}
```

Because `Array.prototype.every` is already well typed you can actually omit most of these types:

```
function subscriptionsReady(handles: Array<Object>) {
  return handles.every(handle => handle.ready());
}
```

And Flow will be able to infer everything.

Also, you may want to add a basic type for the handle instead of `object` like this:

```
type Handle = { ready(): boolean };

function subscriptionsReady(handles: Array<Handle>) {
  return handles.every(handle => handle.ready());
}
```

This will improve the errors that get generated by Flow when you misuse the api.

In general you should try to define these types instead of using `Object`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L204 (where the overloaded signature for `Array#reduce` is declared):

The return type of the `reduce` call (and of the closure passed to it) when you leave out the second argument to `reduce` must match the element type `Object`. Since you instead have it as `boolean`, you have to pass in an initial value of typed `boolean`.

Your code is relying on a dynamic check to distinguish the two cases, but that's too clever for Flow.